# c++ singleton, stackoverflows example does not work

Tags: c++, singleton

I am trying to make a singleton with gcc

I found several examples on stackoverflow, unfortunately they do not work for me.

Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef GLOBALINFO_H
#define GLOBALINFO_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class GlobalInfo
{
    private:
        GlobalInfo();
        GlobalInfo(GlobalInfo const&);
            GlobalInfo& operator=(GlobalInfo const&);


    public:
        static GlobalInfo& GetInstance();
        virtual ~GlobalInfo();

        bool isFullScreen;
        int screenWidth;
        int screenHeight;
        string title;

    protected:
};

#endif // GLOBALINFO_H
```

here is my .cpp:

```
#include "GlobalInfo.h"

GlobalInfo::GlobalInfo()
{
    isFullScreen = false;
    screenWidth = 800;
    screenHeight = 600;
    cout << "creating GlobalInfo" << endl;
}

GlobalInfo::~GlobalInfo()
{
}

GlobalInfo &GlobalInfo::GetInstance() {
    static GlobalInfo instance;
    return instance;
}
```

GNU C says:

```
include\GlobalInfo.h|12|error: 'GlobalInfo::GlobalInfo(const GlobalInfo&)' is private|
```

If i remove

```
GlobalInfo(GlobalInfo const&);
GlobalInfo& operator=(GlobalInfo const&);
```

from the header, i am getting a actual copy of the singleton, which is bad in this situation, as i use the isFullScreen to hold information depending on user input.

Comment: [I'm sure you know what you're doing, I just thought I'd point out that singletons are a very controversial design pattern. If you search on SO, or the internet, you'll find a wealth of discussion.]

Comment: Yeah, i know, but i read quite a few books by quite smart people that use singleton. I am not sure why controversy designs should mean 'do not use it', everything is controversy on the internet. I need a global scope for accessing a few things from anywhere in my game (hence the name GlobalInfo). Being a long time C programmer (>20 years) but relatively new to C++ i do not know what better way to achieve this then via singleton. The C way, using 'extern bool isFullScreen' for sure is even worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do you actually use the singleton class? You are supposed to get a compile error when trying to invoke the copy constructor since the only method of getting the instance of the singleton should be via GetInstance. Perhaps you forgot to use the reference in the calling code:

```
GlobalInfo& gi = GlobalInfo::GetInstance();
```

If you forget the & operator you would effectively be attempting to copy the singleton, which correctly results in a compile error.